# remembering CSS properties

Tags: css

I have a difficulty in remembering the names of properties in CSS. I don't know if I'm the only one or is it normal? My question is: is it OK if I use a cheat sheet? and do most desiners use something like that?

If so, please give me a link to a good reference (cheat sheet) for CSS properties.

Comment: School teaches you that everything must be memorized, but fortunately the Real World is nothing like that.

Comment: I totally agree with that @Juhana. But there are some things you should just remember because it represents that you've been practicing it a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloadable PDF cheatsheet: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/13/css-3-cheat-sheet-pdf/

Preview [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160414113235/http://media.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/images/css3-cheat-sheet/preview.gif) (archived)

[image: CSS Cheatsheet]

Answer (score 0):

as @Petar Suggested, you should use a normal IDE which will guide you.
On the other hand, in time you will be able to remember what you need, practice, practice, practice.

if you need a "Cheat sheet" this should be a good one:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

It's always okay to use a reference. The more you write CSS the less you will need one. For example if you can't remember attributes like width, height, margin, padding. You definitely need to practice more.

For more complicated stuff like css3 gradients and transitions, I use this resource here.

> http://css3generator.com/

Let me know if you need something else.

Answer (score 0):

I personally Use Aptana studio. It detects errors and auto completes property names etc. However http://www.w3schools.com/css/  is a good refference and over time you will just remember them for the most part.

Comment: A far better (more complete, up-to-date and precise) than w3schools is the MDN CSS Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/CSS_Reference

Answer (score -1):

You can try this,
[elizabethcastro](http://www.elizabethcastro.com/html/extras/cssref.html)